# GLFW input handling not working as intended

Tags: c++, input, glfw

So this may be a newbie question regarding GLFW, but I seem to be having an interesting issue. So I'm developing a simple input handling class using GLFW, specifically utilizing static methods to allow only requiring the inclusion of the header file to use the methods. So this is my code thus far...

InputHandler.cpp

```
#include "InputHandler.h"

GLFWwindow *Input::m_Window;
bool Input::isDown;
std::vector<int> Input::keyCache;

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    for (int _key = 0; _key < Input::keyCache.size(); _key++)
    {
        if (key == Input::keyCache[_key] && action == GLFW_PRESS || key == Input::keyCache[_key] && action == GLFW_REPEAT)
            Input::isDown = true;
        else
            Input::isDown = false;
    }
}

void Input::processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    m_Window = window;
}

bool Input::isKeyDown(int key)
{
    keyCache.push_back(key);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(m_Window, key_callback);
    return isDown;
}
```

InputHandler.h

```
#pragma once

#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <vector>

class Input
{
public:
    static bool isDown;
    static std::vector<int> keyCache;
private:
    static GLFWwindow *m_Window;

public:
    static void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);
    static bool isKeyDown(int key);
    static bool isKeyUp(int key);
    static int getMouseX();
    static int getMouseY();
};
```

However, whenever I call the isKeyDown method, which will return true or false based on if the key is down or not, multiple times, the program seems to only respond to the last key mentioned. For example, if I use the code...

```
if (Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_W) || Input::isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_Q))
        std::cout << "Key is down" << std::endl;
```

only the Q key will trigger the statement, W does nothing. I have gone through GLFW's site multiple times, the input guide is where I learned the necessary things needed to receive the input, and it also seems that no one else has had this issue, as I have searched and searched for anything. If anyone could help, by explaining possible issues or pointing me in the right direction in terms of finding the answer myself, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What do you think key_callback does when both W and Q are in the cache, and only W is pressed? Answer: It sets isDown to true, then it sets isDown to false, then it returns. So isDown is false in that case.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense to me now. I probably should have understood that before, but I'll keep telling myself that it's late and that I'm tired. Thank you for taking the time to respond @immibis

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured out my issue. I was WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY overcomplicating it. So, my issue was that the key callback was only able to ever handle one key, and it was completely unnecessary. So, my fix involved removing the key callback, the keyCache and the isDown variable, and simply changing isKeyDown to...

```
bool Input::isKeyDown(int key)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(m_Window, key))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I'm sorry for how ridiculously incompetent I have shown myself to be. Well, now I know how the key callback works! xD